# How to change a string into a formatted string?

Tags: python, console

I want to change a source string:

```
str1 = 'abc-ccd_2013'
```

into the following target string:

```
str2 = 'abc\-ccd\_2013'.
```

All `'-'` should be replaced with `'\-'` and all `'_'` should be replaced into `'\_'`.

The following method is not working:

```
    >>> str1
    'abc-ccd_2013'
    >>> a1 = str1.replace("-","\\-")
    >>> a1
    'abc\\-ccd_2013'
    >>> a1 = str1.replace("-","\-")
    >>> a1
    'abc\\-ccd_2013'
    >>> a1 = str1.replace('-','\-')
    >>> a1
    'abc\\-ccd_2013'
    >>> a1 = str1.replace(r'-',r'\-')
    >>> a1
    'abc\\-ccd_2013'
    >>>
```

Comment: So what's happening ? Are you aware that you have use ` instead of ' ?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Try setting `str1 = 'abc-ccd_2013'` (ie backticks replaced by single quotes).

Comment: @XavierC., I've updated the post, please check it.

Comment: It's working. You're just misinterpreting what you see in the Python console where it's showing you the _representation_ of the resulting strings—that's also why it's showing the quotes around them.

Comment: @mining you should gave a look at chris-rands answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP just doesn't understand how the Python console displays information.

Comment: @martineau, thank you. I just know it has a difference between running  python script and running in the console interpreter.

Comment: @martineau, the code works ok with a python script, but in the console, it didn't work.

Comment: It _does_ work in the Python console. It's just that in the console it displays the `repr()` of the last result, not the `str()`. Same difference as `print('abc\-ccd\_2013')` and `print(repr('abc\-ccd\_2013'))`.

Comment: @martineau, thanks. In fact, there are many strings in file `A.bib`, I just want to replace them with `str1`-like strings. I just know use a bash script `grep -rl "abc2013ccd" A.bib | xargs sed -i 's/abc2013ccd/abc\-ccd\_2013/g'`. So I first find all `abc2013ccd`-like strings in `A.bib` and generate some bash scripts in a python script. Then I can run the bash script to replace all `abc2013ccd`-like strings into `str1`-like ones. There is a one-to-one relationship between `abc2013ccd` and `abc-ccd_2013`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work and can be combined to a single expression:

```
>>> print("abc-ccd_2013".replace("-","\-").replace("_","\_"))
abc\-ccd\_2013
```

Note the difference of `print` vs `repr`:

```
>>> "abc-ccd_2013".replace("-","\-").replace("_","\_")
'abc\\-ccd\\_2013'
```

Is equivalent to:

```
>>> print(repr("abc-ccd_2013".replace("-","\-").replace("_","\_")))
'abc\\-ccd\\_2013'
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. When printing raw string, '\' is replaced with '\\' so it does not interpret it as escape character used for e.g. endline character '\n', tab character '\t' and so on.
Try command
`print str2` or `print a1`
and it will be fine.

Update: Even stackoverflow replaces '\\' with '\', so instead I have to type '\\\' (to type this I had to use 5 slashes) :D

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following :

```
str1 = 'abc-ccd_2013'
repl = ('-', '\-'), ('_', '\_')
print reduce(lambda a1, a2: a1.replace(*a2), repl, str1)
```

You will have to use the print function to get your desired result.